# Expression not working in MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, expression

Below is the expression it is used to concatenate but for some reason the result is giving just first two letter of each string. I'm little confuse what's wrong with it. Below expression is working fine in sybase but not in sql server.Thank you
Example:

```
F
G
Required Output:
For Young Musicians Program
GV- Record Sheet.
IF(ISNULL(fd_m_an_report),'', fd_m_an_report )  +  
IF((NOT ISNULL(fd_m_an_report)) AND (NOT ISNULL(fd_m_comment)), '~r~n~r~n', '') + 
IF(ISNULL(fd_m_comment ),'',  fd_m_comment)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid SQL Server statement at all. Isnull requires 2 parameters, if can't be used like that...

Comment: Is this SQL Server? `ISNULL` function replaces provided text with what you decide if it's NULL

Comment: Yes, Evaldas. I'm actually migrating code from sybase to sql server. I'm facing error on this expression.

Comment: Please add examples, the inputs and expected results

Comment: It's not clear from your Sybase code what you are trying to do.   At least not to someone who has never used Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are using Excel functions.  To get something similar in SQL Server syntax you need:

```
select 
    ISNULL(fd_m_an_report,'')  +  
    case when fd_m_an_report + fd_m_comment is null then '' else '~r~n~r~n' end + 
    ISNULL(fd_m_comment,'')
from MyTable
```